# Jquery .on() not working with "e"

Tags: jquery

**working**

```
$('.newbubble').live('click', function(e){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

**Not Working** (here i want to get e.pageX and e.pageY)

```
$('.newbubble').on('click', function(e){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

**Again Working** this one without "e"

```
$('.newbubble').on('click', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

Can anyone please help me with this, how can i get e.pageX with **.on()**

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Did you try delegation with `on` ?

Comment: Works fine for me... what version of jQuery are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/gd7Lg/

Comment: I am using jQuery version 1.7.2

Comment: Does the `.newbubble` present when this code is executed or it is added dynamically?

Comment: .newbubble is added dynamically.

Comment: @hamidraza Than you have the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I imagine, `.newbubble` doesn't exist on DOM ready, so you'll need to delegate.

For example :

```
$('body').on('click', '.newbubble', function(e){
    // here
});
```

Read [the doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: If possible, don't attach the event to the `body`, attach it to something closer, a container `div` or something. That's faster.

Comment: @hamidraza you should really find a container closer to the element you need than `body`.

Comment: thanks.. i'll change that from body.. actually bubble is a class of <li>, which getting added dynamically.

Comment: Then, attach the event to the parent `ul`/`ol`.

Comment: @Alex you beat me to it, I clicked on another question thinking "wait, you forgot something earlier" and ding. But as I said, he should read the doc first ;)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$(document).on('click','.newbubble', function(e){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

Comment: @Alex i do not know the nearest parent of `.newbubble` that's why i put `document`

Comment: Yeah of course, but you could mention it. Obviously the TS doesn't know how event delegation works and this is pretty important.

Comment: i am working on this : http://106.51.95.11/test/snl/
i think, you guys can help me, improving the code.

Comment: what is the issue everything seems fine

Comment: there is no issue, i was expecting that u'll suggest me on improvement of jquery code.